# How to split a portion of URL with text and number, into text/number

Tags: regex, url

I have this link:
xyz.forum.com/tech/1823630913/status4906130760727773.html

But I want to convert it into:
abc.site.com/status/4906130760727773

How could I achieve that, pls?

EDIT: BIG Sorry for not making it clear already where and how I intend to use it. 
Sorry again.

But here's how I am looking to use it.
Well, using a Chrome plugin.
This one - http://www.requestly.in/rules/
It allows you to provide URL and the regex to be applied.

Please check it out, and let me know how I should go ahead here.

Comment: what have you tried? you can split between the /'s

Comment: Which langeage you use?

Comment: Give more examples of input an desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and add results to your url

```
 link="xyz.forum.com/tech/1823630913/status4906130760727773.html"
 m=re.search('([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]*.html',link)
 if m:
     st=m.group(0)
     print m #prints status
 n=re.search('([0-9]*).html',link)
 if n:
     no=n.group(0)
     print no #prints number
```

Comment: Thanks for finding time for this. I have updated the query, so please have a re-look of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Pick a regex

`(?:https?:\/\/)?xyz\.forum\.com\/tech\/\d+\/status(\d+)\.html`

`xyz\.forum\.com\/tech\/\d+\/status(\d+)\.html`

`.*\/status(\d+)\.html?`

`.*status(\d+)\..*`

`.*[a-z]+(\d+)\..*`

`.*(\d+)\..*`

`.*(\d{16}).*`

Then replace with :

```
abc.site.com/status/$1
```

Or use your programming language to get capture group 1.
And add that to "abc.site.com/status/"

Comment: Thanks a lot! But here's something.
I have updated the query, so please have a re-look of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, but it's not worth it to install some random unknown plugin just to solve someone's issues with it. To much of a potential security risk.